# How to set Two Markers in One Dataset in MPAndroid (Line) Chart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

One way I could think of achieving 2 markers in the same dataset is by creating a custom class implementing IMarker and setting up 2 separate layouts in it.

**MarkerView2.java:**

```
public MarkerView2(Context context, int layoutResource, int layoutResource2) {
        super(context);
        setupLayoutResource(layoutResource);
        setupLayoutResource2(layoutResource2);
    }

private void setupLayoutResource(int layoutResource) {

        // Default usual code..
    }

private void setupLayoutResource2(int layoutResource2) {

        // Default usual code..
    }
```

**Passing both the marker layouts by calling `super` in the CustomMarkerView2.java:**

```
public class CustomMarkerView2 extends MarkerView2 {
    public CustomMarkerView2(Context context, int layoutResource, int layoutResource2) {
        super(context, layoutResource, layoutResource2);

    }
// Rest of the usual implementations..
}
```

**In the fragment where the LineChart is being set:**

```
CustomMarkerView2 customMarkerView2 = new CustomMarkerView2(view.getContext(), R.layout.custom_marker_view2, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
lineChart.setMarker(customMarkerView2);
```

Before this, I created 2 separate Implementations of IMarker but only one marker was being set in the chart so I did what I've outlined above.

I am also providing an image which depicts where I am currently at and what I'm trying to achieve. I want the Dot-Icon to be drawn on the value being intersected by the vertical highlighter and the Description-Icon to be drawn on the top.

I was able to set either the Dot-Icon or the Desc-Icon correctly by using the default provided `MarkerView` class by adjusting `return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2f), -getHeight());` in the `getOffset()` function, but cannot align both of them accordingly using my own custom `MarkerView2`.

[image]